# Change spree application layout file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Is it possible to use my own application layout file in my main rails app instead of spree's? I have my main app already setup with devise and then added spree. Spree frontend uses

`frontend/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb`

in its own gem as its layout and I read how to override that file with my own in `app/overrides` or Deface, but I don't want to duplicate the content that is already in my `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

I'm looking to use my own file instead or overriding spree's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a `app/view/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb` in your rails app and rails will pick your file
2. Set your own layout with `Spree::Config[:layout]` in an initializer (ex: `Spree::Config[:layout]='application'`)

Comment: Spree::Config[:layout]='application' This worked exactly as I needed. Is this documented any where if I need to make other changes?

Comment: For some reasons, changing Spree::Config[:layout] did not work for me. But overriding spree_application.html.erb did. Thanks!

Comment: Second solution with `Spree::Config[:layout]`also works for me but I had to use `'layouts/application'`, not just `'application'`.

Comment: `Spree::Config[:layout]='application'` worked for me but now I cannot switch back to `spree_application` layout. Removing that line does not help. If I want to switch to any layout then I have to mention it.

Comment: In what file did you add it?

Answer (score 2):

`Spree::Config[:layout]='application'` worked for me. But when I tried to switch to the spree default layout by removing this line, it did not work. After spending almost an hour I was able to switch back to default `Spree::Config[:layout]='spree/layouts/spree_application'`
Adding this answer just in case someone else gets stuck with similiar error.